# Interface Dependencies

Tags: c#, oop

When you create an interface and you know you will have a dependency on another, do you make the constructor part of the interface?

In my case, I want to create

An IClientReceiveRecorder that I can give to a client and have all the network traffic collected for a short test session. It is probably just going to contain a collection of strings.

An IEvaluator that can get all the messages received and implement various things we want to test for. For example, I might have a concrete Evaluator that tests whether or not all the strings contain the letter 'c'.

I know that any IEvaluator is going to need a IClientReceiveRecorder to get the messages it is to evaluate.

So, I see a few options.
Do I do something like

```
interface IEvaluator
{
    IEvaluator(IClientReceiveRecorder);

    void Evaluate();
}
```

It doesn't compile, so I am guessing not.

Perhaps I do something like

```
interface IEvaluator
{
    void Evaluate(IClientReceiveRecorder);
}
```

Or, do I just leave it up to the concrete class to take a IClientReceiveRecorder in its constuctor?

Comment: interfaces do not have constructors

Comment: So, how do I express the intended dependency?

Comment: What you describe are implementation concerns that should be left up to the concrete implementations. Other wise forego interface and use abstract class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The straight forward answer is to leave implementation detail up to the concrete class.

Knowing that the implementation of `IEvaluator` is going to have a dependency of `IClientReceiveRecorder` is an implementation detail and would not be included in the `IEvaluator` interface.

If you know that the interface is going to be composed of another interface you could do something like the following:

```
interface IEvaluator
{
    IClientReceiveRecorder { get; set; }

    void Evaluate();
}
```

How that property is populated is an implementation detail and should not be part of the interface.

Answer (score 5):

You really shouldn't need to.

An interface isn't necessarily a contract of *dependencies*, it's a contract of *functionality*.  Any implementation can expose its dependencies via constructor(s).  But in the event that a different implementation has different (or no) dependencies, it still implements the interface and exposes the functionality.

One thing you *could* do is expose a property getter in the interface which shows the dependency.  This would at least imply to implementing types that they need to expose a getter with the intended type, which happens to be a dependency.

Another alternative entirely might be to use an abstract class instead of an interface.  (Understanding the differences between them, of course.)  That abstract class can also use a constructor to expose the dependency, and implementing types would have to use that constructor.  This alternative could necessitate other changes throughout your code, so it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave any mention of the `IClientReceiveRecorder` out of the interface. As others have mentioned it's an implementation detail.

Further to this point, you do not know of any further uses you may have for the `IEvaluator` interface. If you keep the interface as follows:

```
public IEvaluator
{
    void Evaluate();
}
```

then this is a very flexible interface that can be reused for any class that wants to implement evaluation semantics in future. This ties in with the Interface Segregation Principle and Single Responsibility Principle and helps to keep your classes decoupled.

Therefore, instead of including the `IClientReceiveRecorder` in the `IEvaluate`interface simply pass it via the constructor:

```
public ConcreteEvaluator : IEvaluate
{
    private readonly IClientReceiveRecorder recorder;

    public ConcreteEvaluator(IClientReceiveRecorder recorder)
    {
        this.recorder = recorder;
    }

    public void Evaluate()
    {
        this.recorder.DoSomeRecording();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces don't have constructors, as you've already discovered. That's because the point of using an interface is to have your class interact with *contracts* for other classes, not actual implementations. That interaction is defined in the interface, but how the actual implementation gets created is not part of that interface. Ideally a class should not know how the abstractions it depends on get created.

That's a reason why constructor injection is helpful for keeping classes decoupled.

If I do this, which is a very common pattern:

```
public class ClassThatDependsOnSomething
{
    private readonly IDependsOnThis _dependsOnThis;

    public ClassThatDependsOnSomething(IDependsOnThis dependsOnThis)
    {
        _dependsOnThis = dependsOnThis;
    }
}
```

then the class interacts with the interface it depends on without being responsible for creating it - calling its constructor. That keeps it truly decoupled. If my class calls the constructor, that means it knows the difference between one implementation that has one constructor vs. another implementation with a different constructor. At that point it's coupled to the implementation.

Also, what if the implementation of `IDependsOnThis` has its own dependencies? If `ClassThatDependsOnSomething` calls the implementations's constructor and passes in those dependencies, where will get those from? It would have to create them too.

This is why we use dependency injection containers. To oversimplify, a DI container allows us to declare what all of the implementations will be for all of the interfaces we use. Then we can ask the container to resolve an implementation of an interface. If that implementation has a constructor that requires more interfaces, it resolves those. And so on, and on. So when working with one class, you only need to be concerned with the that one class and the interfaces it depends on, but you shouldn't have to think about the details of the implementations of those interfaces.

One of the key benefits of this is that since a class depends on interfaces passed into its constructor, you can write unit tests for the class and pass in "mocks" or "test doubles," really simple classes that implement the interfaces and provide dummy responses to method calls. By controlling exactly what all of the dependencies do, you can test that your class behaves exactly as expected.