# Should dependencies in UML diagrams exist for both Interfaces and their implementing class?

Tags: java, dependencies, uml

Say I have the following Java interface. Does `ModalDrawer` have a dependency on `model`, `pane` and `level` in my UML class diagram?

```
public interface ModalDrawer {
    void draw(GameEngine model, Pane pane);
    void update(Level level);
}
```

To me, it makes sense for the class **implementing** `ModalDrawer` to have those dependencies but not really for the interface `ModalDrawer`. My confusion around this point is compounded by the response in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212669/7489488). It has the following quote:

> An interface isn't necessarily a contract of dependencies, it's a
>   contract of functionality. Any implementation can expose its
>   dependencies via constructor(s).

By that logic, is the answer to my question "no"?

Comment: Make sure you drawing a class diagram or ...?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to a UML class diagram

Comment: If you have implementation of `ModelDrawer`, the dependency should be drawn from `implementation` to `interface` of `GameEngine` (if exists), which meets Dependence Inversion Principle of Design Pattern.

Comment: Furthermore, think about  a class with more than one interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. ModalDrawer uses GameEngine, Pane and Level to define its parameters, hence it depends on these three classes, because without their existence, it would have undefined parameter types.